# How to Sum values in two different columns from different rows (Row 1 column A + Row 0 Column B)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 different columns, one for Current_Month, the other Next_Month. They relate to the revenue to be recognised for a payment made by a customer.

e.g. Customer A starts subscription of $20 on 15/06/21. Customer A also end their Subscription in August.

| CustomerID | Month | Curr_Month_Revenue | Next_Month_Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 06.21 | $10 | $10 |
| A | 07.21 | $10 | $10 |
| A | 08.21 | $10 | $10 |

I would like to create a new table, which sums the Curr_Month column with the Next_month column of the previous row (month-1), to display the revenues to be recognised for each month.

The table would result in:

| CustomerID | Month | Recognised_Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 06.21 | $10 |
| A | 07.21 | $20 |
| A | 08.21 | $20 |
| A | 09.21 | $10 |

Not sure how to achieve this in SQL

Comment: You can achieve this behavior using `LAG` and `LEAD` function in SQL. More about it here. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions

Comment: Can you check if my edit reflects the idea of your data? In case it is wrong, please rollback or update it. @Rod

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve it.

1- Self-join with joining condition as previous month:

```
SELECT
      t1.customerid,
      t1.month,
      (t1.Curr_Month_Revenue + t2.Curr_Month_Revenue) Recognised_Revenue
    FROM
      table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      table1 t2
    ON
      t1.customerid = t2.customerid
      AND t1.month = t2.month-1
```

2- Lag or Lead funtion

```
lag(Curr_Month_Revenue )over(partition by customerid  order by month) prev_mont_revenue
```